# How to use callback function in React hooks when value is submitted?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am building an app using React hooks.

but the problem is I can intentionally click the button twice to occurs an error.

So I want to disabled the button while I send api request using useState when I clicked the button.

However sending api and useState both work asynchrously, it might hard to expect how it works.

Therefore I have come up with an idea of using callback function of setState in React but since I am new to React hooks, it is hard to grasp of idea how to use setState callback function in React hooks.

Here is the code:

```
    const submitForm = (values: IAgreeMentValues) => {
      const userActivate = Object.assign(props.currentUserObject, values, {c})
      delete userActivate.email
      const userActivateJSON = JSON.stringify(userActivate)

      if(values.is14YearsOldOrOlder && values.isAcceptedPrivacyPolicy && values.isAcceptedTerm) {

        setButtonState(true)

        activateUser(userActivateJSON).then(response => {
          if(response.data.result.canLogin) {
            popupStore.add({
              type: 'alert',
              title: t('signUp.agreeMent.registeredCompleted'),
              actionString: t('popUpAlert.ok'),
              onSubmit: isMobile ? pushToAppStore : pushToLogin
            })
          } else {
            popupStore.add({
              type: 'alert',
              title: t('error.occured'),
              actionString: t('popUpAlert.ok')
            })
          }
        })
        .catch(response => {
          setButtonState(false)
          popupStore.add({
            type: 'alert',
            title: response.response.data.error.message,
            actionString: t('popUpAlert.ok'),
          })
        })
      } else {
        popupStore.add({
          type: 'alert',
          title: t('signUp.agreeMent.mustBeChecked'),
          actionString: t('popUpAlert.ok')
        })
      }
    };


    return (
      <>
      <div className='signup-step-wrap'>
        <div className='agree-check-box'>
        <Formik enableReinitialize={true} initialValues={termsAllSelected}
          onSubmit={ (values) => submitForm(values)}>
            {({ values, handleChange, handleSubmit }) => (
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <ul className='check'>
              <li>
                <Field type='checkbox' name={`isAcceptedMarketingEmail`} id={`agree4`} onChange={handleChange} />
                <label htmlFor={`agree4`}>{t('signUp.agreeMent.isAcceptedMarketingEmail')}</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Field type='checkbox' name={`isAcceptedMarketingSms`} id={`agree5`} onChange={handleChange} />
                <label htmlFor={`agree5`}>{t('signUp.agreeMent.isAcceptedMarketingSms')}</label>
              </li>
              </ul>
              <div className='btn-btm-signin'>
                <button className='btn-signin active' type='submit' disabled={currentButtonState} style={currentButtonState ? {background: '#e2e2e2'}:{background: '#1f1f1f'}}>{t('signUp.agreeMent.next')}</button>
              </div>
              </form>
            )}
        </Formik>
        </div>
      </div>
      </>
    )
```

Comment: I don't see where you have set `const [currentButtonState, setButtonState] = React.useState(false);`. Here's an example https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-flower-c1bh7

Comment: Thank you. Just like the example, I put setButtonState at the top inside of submitForm function.

Answer (score 0):

You should also `setButtonState(false)` in `then`

```js
activateUser(userActivateJSON).then(response => {
          if(response.data.result.canLogin) {
            popupStore.add({
              type: 'alert',
              title: t('signUp.agreeMent.registeredCompleted'),
              actionString: t('popUpAlert.ok'),
              onSubmit: isMobile ? pushToAppStore : pushToLogin
            })
          } else {
            popupStore.add({
              type: 'alert',
              title: t('error.occured'),
              actionString: t('popUpAlert.ok')
            })
          }
          setButtonState(false)
        })
```